# context.SaveChangesAsync() - The method or operation is not implemented

Tags: sql-server

In attempting to seed a SQL database table I get an error, The method or operation is not implemented, in this line of code:

```
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This is the surrounding code:

```
                if (!context.ProductBrands.Any())
                {
                    var brandsData =
                        File.ReadAllText(path + @"\SeedData\brands.json");

                    var brands = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ProductBrand>>(brandsData);

                    foreach (var item in brands)
                    {
                        context.ProductBrands.Add(item);
                    }

                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
```

This is what the SQL table looks like:
[image]

This is the DbContext file:

```
   public class StoreContext : DbContext
    {
        public StoreContext(DbContextOptions<StoreContext> options) : base(options)
        {}

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductBrand> ProductBrands { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Products");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            if (Database.ProviderName == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite")
            {
                foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
                {
                    var properties = entityType.ClrType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(decimal));
                    var dateTimeProperties = entityType.ClrType.GetProperties()
                        .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTimeOffset));

                    foreach (var property in properties)
                    {
                        modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.Name).Property(property.Name).HasConversion<double>();
                    }

                    foreach (var property in dateTimeProperties)
                    {
                        modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.Name).Property(property.Name)
                            .HasConversion(new DateTimeOffsetToBinaryConverter());
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
```